# WPF Databinding: Don't overwrite pre-populated values

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a MenuItem that I'd like to populate with sub-items.  However, I'd like for it to keep the items it already has:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Profiles">
    <MenuItem Header="_New Profile..." />
    <Separator />
    <!-- Databind here! -->
</MenuItem>
```

However, when I try to use normal declarative databinding it eliminates the two subitems I've declared.

I'm sure there has to be a way to do this but I can't figure it out and I'm not sure any of my Google searches have been that good; can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to utilize a [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742405.aspx):

```
<MenuItem Header="_File">
    <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <MenuItem Header="_New" />
            <Separator />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding MenuItems}" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="E_xit" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: That's perfect.  I knew there must have been some built-in way.

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know you could do that.  Would have saved me some time not too long ago.

Comment: @Rob and @Josh, I must have spent a week solid just pouring through the namespaces when the 4.0 framework came out but even still I find new classes almost weekly!

Comment: @six, I hear ya there, especially with dealing with XAML.  There is always a trick that is easier, it's just a matter of finding it.

Answer (score 1):

It will bind all the items in your collection on the MenuItem, so the only way to keep the items there after your collection is loaded/modified is to ensure those static menu items remain in the collection.

One way to do this is to keep two ItemCollections, one of your static values and one of your dynamic values.  Bind to the dynamic values.  Then before the menu is displayed, merge the collections.  That way you don't have to constantly ensure the static values are place as the first two elements of your binded collection.